# Why recovery of malicious code often fails from packed file?/

Tags: malware, obfuscation

I read it in a paper that recovery of the malicious code often fails from the packed file. Can you tell me some of the possible reasons why it fails?

Comment: Which paper, Can you also go into detail?

Comment: A packed PE file contains everything, looking for payload is just time consuming works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is packed because the author does not want you to reverse the code.
So i would argue the fundamental reason it fails is because the creator is motivated to find new ways to sabotage the effort to unpack the program.
Technically this can take many forms.

But as is said, it is always possible to see what the code does, it can just be very hard. If you were to provide us with the paper you talk about we might be able to give more technical detail.